# Return different types from web scraper method

Tags: c#, web-scraping

*Application Logic*

The software take odds data from an internet site and store them inside my own database, this application is basically a scraper.

There are different types of odds, eg:

1. FullTime
2. Under / Over
3. Double Chance

*My goal*

I want avoid code redundancy, for doing so, I created a method called `GetOddsRow` which returns a type called `GenericOdds`, this is the code:

```
private async Task<List<GenericOdds>> GetOddsRows(Uri fixtureLink, string endpoint, string[] filter)
{
    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
    List<GenericOdds> gos = new List<GenericOdds>();
    int i = 0;

    foreach (string newEndpoint in filter)
    {
        //Make a new endpoint to get the odds type.
        fixtureLink = new Uri(fixtureLink, endpoint + newEndpoint);

        string html = await NetworkHelper.LoadAndWaitForSelector(fixtureLink, _oddsTable);
        doc.LoadHtml(html);

        //Get only the containers that contains data.
        var containers = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='table-container' and not(@style)]");

        //The odds are not available for this container.
        if (containers.ElementAtOrDefault(i) == null)
            break;

        GenericOdds go = new GenericOdds();
        HtmlNode container = containers[i];

        //Get the table which contains the odds.
        HtmlNode table = container.SelectSingleNode(".//table[@class='" + _oddsTableClass + "']");

        //Get the odds description type.
        go.OddsType = container.SelectSingleNode(".//strong[1]//a").InnerText;

        //Get all the rows (odds available).
        go.Odds = table.SelectNodes(".//tbody//tr[normalize-space()]");
        gos.Add(go);

        i++;
    }

    return gos;
}
```

This method have three parameters:

1. **fixtureLink**: is the link of the event that contains the odds
2. **endpoint**: is the odds type
3. **filter**: specify the category of the odds

eg:

```
[fixtureLink]
https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/africa/africa-cup-of-nations/libya-south-africa-0QsEg3I8/?r=1#
[endpoint]
over-under;2;
[filter]
0.50;0
```

The method logic is really simple, I iterate through all the filters available and then join this filter to the endpoint to create a new url, that url will be used to get the odds data.

I store each list of rows (of a specific category) in a new `GenericOdds` which have the following implementation:

```
public class GenericOdds
{
    public HtmlNodeCollection Odds { get; set; }
    public string OddsType { get; set; }
}
```

This allow me to organize the odds rows, so I can easily navigate to that list and see the type of the rows, eg:

```
GenericOdds[0]
     HtmlNodeList => 10 elements
     OddsType => Over 0.5
GenericOdds[1]
     HtmlNodeList => 5 elements
     OddsType => Over 1.5
GenericOdds[2]
     HtmlNodeList => 3 elements
     OddsType => Over 3.5
```

Now I have 10 methods that call `GetOddsRows`, for example of `Over / Under`:

```
public async Task<List<OverUnder>> GetOverUnder(Uri fixtureLink, OddsCategory cat)
{
    List<OverUnder> overUnders = new List<OverUnder>();

    string endpoint = "?r=1#over-under;2;";

    if (cat == OddsCategory.Firsthalf)
        endpoint = "?r=1#over-under;3";
    else if (cat == OddsCategory.Secondhalf)
        endpoint = "?r=1#over-under;4";

    //Odds filters.
    string[] filter = { "0.50;0", "1.50;0", "2.50;0", "3.50;0", "4.50;0", "5.50;0", "6.50;0" };

    List<GenericOdds> gos = await GetOddsRows(fixtureLink, endpoint, filter);

    gos.ForEach(od =>
    {
        foreach(HtmlNode tr in od.Odds)
        {
            OverUnder overUnder = new OverUnder();

            overUnder.Book = tr.SelectSingleNode(".//td//div//a[2]").InnerText;
            overUnder.Description = od.OddsType;

            //Get event odds
            HtmlNode odds = tr.SelectSingleNode(".//td[contains(@class, 'odds')][1]");
            overUnder.Over = OddsUtility.ParseOdds(odds);

            odds = tr.SelectSingleNode(".//td[contains(@class, 'odds')][2]");
            overUnder.Under = OddsUtility.ParseOdds(odds);
            overUnder.Payout = OddsUtility.GetPayout(tr);

            overUnders.Add(overUnder);
        }
    });

    return overUnders;
}
```

as you can see I have an endpoint for the specific type of odds which is `Under / Over`, this type is defined as below:

```
public class OverUnder
{
    public string Book { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public KeyValuePair<decimal?, int> Over { get; set; }
    public KeyValuePair<decimal?, int> Under { get; set; }
    public decimal? Payout { get; set; }
}
```

there is also `OddsCategory` that is an `enum` that allow me to understand which types of odds need to be downloaded.

as I said before, there are also others odds method eg: GetFullTime, GetDoubleChance, GetHalfTime, etc...

all of these methods vary only by:

1. endpoint
2. filter
3. return type

So my goal is to avoid code redundancy, honestly I don't like the solution of `GenericOdds`, I'm looking for a way to return different types from `GetOddsRow`, something like an interface.

Additional methods:

The site is based on ajax request, for handle that I'm using [Puppeteer Sharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PuppeteerSharp/), and I create the following method:

```
public static async Task<string> LoadAndWaitForSelector(Uri url, string selector)
{
    var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions
    {
        Headless = true,
        ExecutablePath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CHROME_PATH"),
    });
    using (Page page = await browser.NewPageAsync())
    {
        await page.GoToAsync(url.ToString());
        await page.WaitForSelectorAsync(selector);
        return await page.GetContentAsync();
    }
}
```

this method wait for the selector requested by the caller and return the odds table generated by the ajax request.

Also, if you are looking for another odds type:

```
public async Task<List<HalfTime>> GetHalfTime(Uri fixtureLink)
{
    List<HalfTime> hfts = new List<HalfTime>();

    string endpoint = "?r=1#ht-ft;2;";

    //Odds filters.
    string[] filter = { "27", 30", "33" };

    List<GenericOdds> gos = await GetOddsRows(fixtureLink, endpoint, filter);

    gos.ForEach(od =>
    {
        foreach(HtmlNode tr in od.Odds)
        {
            HalfTimeFullTime hf = new HalfTimeFullTime();

            hf.Book = tr.SelectSingleNode(".//td//div//a[2]").InnerText;
            hf.Description = header.InnerText;

            //Get odds.
            HtmlNode odds = tr.SelectSingleNode(".//td[contains(@class, 'odds')][1]");
            hf.Odds = OddsUtility.ParseOdds(odds);

            hfts.Add(hf);
        }
    });

    return hfts;
}
```

and type:

```
public class HalfTime
{
    public string Book { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public KeyValuePair<decimal?, int> Odds { get; set; }
}
```